# How to insert new line + value if condition is fulfilled

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I need a bash/sed/grep/awk command for adding a new line and a zero value if the line before is an IP. Like this:

INPUT:

```
1.0.0.6
1.0.130.99
44
1.0.210.94
43
1.0.212.145
43
1.0.254.4
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.138
```

OUTPUT:

```
1.0.0.6 
0
1.0.130.99
44
1.0.210.94
43
1.0.212.145
43
1.0.254.4
0
1.1.1.1
0
1.1.1.138
0
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

**Print `0` after IP**

First match the ip using a [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), like this:

```
/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/
```

The regex is self explanatory and can be used to identify an ip using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) for instance. In following `awk` one-liner we will check for lines that are ip addresses and print a `0` if the condition is met.

```
awk --re-interval '{print} /[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/ { print 0 }' file
```

Where file is the input file in the current directory. This should yield the desired output.

**Print `0` in between IPs**

```
awk --re-interval '{
    if ($0 ~ /[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/) { 
        if (prev)
            print 0
        prev=1
    } else {
        prev=""
    }
    print
}' file
```

This should print a `0` when the current line is an IP and the previous was one too (untested).

Comment: thanks very much! It works fine except that it prints everytime the 0 after the IP. It should just print 0 if the next line is also an IP. How can I implement a further condition so that it just adds 0 if there is no other value  like 44 or 43 in the next line?

Answer (score 0):

thank you again very much. It works fine your code.

I just realized that there is another problem in my data. I need to replace a range of numbers with a certain number. I really tried it hard to code it myself with sed (like `sed "s/[33-64]/64/"`) or awk, but always get wrong results. It tends to replace single digits instead of numbers...
What I need would be: Replacing 0-32 -> 32, 33-64 -> 64, 65-128 -> 128, 129-255 -> 255

INPUT:

```
1.208.121.246
48
49
48
49
1.208.121.250
135
150
1.209.125.134
17
1.209.121.250
99
```

OUPTUT:

```
1.208.121.246
64
64
64
64
1.208.121.250
255
255
1.209.125.134
32
1.209.121.250
128
```

Would very appreciate a last advice!